# Dynamic graph with xml and xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, graph

How can I make a dynamic graph from a XML file and XSLT or HTML. I've got a projekt going already so i need to keep on using XML and one of XSLT or HTML. The XML file has historical data about prices and will update about every 2 seconds. So I am looking for ideas and advice how to make a graph that updates the new values every 2 seconds.

The graph is to be shown in a browser.

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "dynamic graph". Some kind of data structure? Or rather a visual graphic for a human user? Possibly something else?

Comment: This questions is too broad to be asked here. If you have a more specific question, please edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

In web browser you can read data only from those files, that are served by web-server.

You need to make a javascript method which will re-read XML file via AJAX request each 2 seconds, and apply the XML data to XSLT/HTML part.